# How to fmt.Printf("%b",...) but with the number of digits specified?

Tags: go

I'd like to control many digits are printed by `fmt.Printf("%b",...)`. But I don't see a way to so. Is it possible?

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Comment: Exactly as it says in the docs. `%b` is not special, it works the same as `%d` or `%f`.

Comment: _control many digits are printed_ means can be less number of digit you can print  ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `%nb` where `n` is the width. By default it is left padded with spaces. To pad with zeros, use `%0nb`.

For example:

```
fmt.Printf("%b\n", 3)
fmt.Printf("%03b\n", 3)
fmt.Printf("%04b\n", 3)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IpRw1HADagk)):

```
11
011
0011
```